# Adding Client SSL certificate to the WCF binding

Tags: wcf, ssl, binding, client, certificate

Is there way to attach client side SSL file (.pfx) file in WCF binding? I don't want to use certificate store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
webServiceProxyInstance.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("path to the pfx file", "password to open the private key");
```